# Devise :confirmable activation link in email expires too quickly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activation, devise-confirmable

When users register on my website, they get an email with an activation link. This link expires after about 3 hours.

How can I customize Devise (`2.0.0`) to keep this activation link Valid for 7 days?

Here's what I've tried:

```
# Model:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :confirmable
end

# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.confirm_within = 7.days
end
```

Email activation link is still expiring after about 3 hours. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the exact version of Devise you are using?

Comment: According to my `Gemfile.lock`: devise (2.0.0)

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using 2.0.0 and not the latest version?

Comment: `confirm_within` was renamed to `allow_unconfirmed_access_for` in Devise 2.0. It provides a "grace period" when the user can login to the web site without confirmation.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?